# I want to display inputs from one class in another class but it's not working

Tags: java

I want to try a simple 3 variable input to pass to another class and display it but it's not working. I have two separate classes.

main.java :

'''

```
import.java.util.*;

public class Main{
   String firstName, lastName, email;
   Scanner display = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Enter first name: ");
   firstName = display.nextLine();
   System.out.println("Enter last name: ");
   lastName = display.nextLine();
   System.out.println("Enter email: ");
   email = display.nextLine();
}
```

'''

print.java :

'''

```
import.java.util.*;

class print{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Main myObj = new Main();
         System.out.println(myObj.firstName);
         System.out.println(myObj.lastName);
         System.out.println(myObj.email);
    }
}
```

'''

Comment: you can't run code *directly* in a class. You can run it inside some *function*. A class's *constructor* is a special type of function, which automatically is called whenever an instance of the class is created. If you put the code there, it is automatically called. Otherwise, you have to manually call the function in order for the code in it to run. In this case, your prompts should never get called at all.

Answer (score 1):

With your code as template and the following changes it works. I

- put the input processing into a [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html)
- added a [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) so that the scanner will be closed
- just made `print` a public class to make it executable
- and made class `Main` package visible so that there is only one public class

```java
import java.util.*;

class Main {
    String firstName, lastName, email;
    Main() {
        try (Scanner display = new Scanner(System.in)) { 
            System.out.println("Enter first name: ");
            firstName = display.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter last name: ");
            lastName = display.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter email: ");
            email = display.nextLine();
        }
    }
}

public class print {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main myObj = new Main();
        System.out.println(myObj.firstName);
        System.out.println(myObj.lastName);
        System.out.println(myObj.email);
    }
}
```

```
$ javac print.java
$ java print 
Enter first name: 
John
Enter last name: 
Smith
Enter email: 
js@js.com
John
Smith
js@js.com
$
```

Please note that it is not a good idea to put several classes into one file. It is here only done in order to make it easily reproducible.

What you are trying to with classes and a scanner is described in detail on https://hackr.io/blog/best-way-to-learn-java. You might want to take a look there!

Comment: thank you for your help. I will try it out and check out the link.

Comment: actually its not what i was looking for I know how to do it in one class i want the user inputs in one separate class and the display in another separate class.

Comment: thank you. works perfectly. I didnt make a function.